# Proof of $\rho(A) < 1$ iff $\|A\|<1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, proof-explanation

We have, $\rho(A) \leq \|A\|$
where $\rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$.

Now there is a corollary
that $\rho(A) < 1$ iff $\|A\|<1$
it is clear that when $\|A\|<1$ then $\rho(A)<1$

but how to show that if $\rho(A)<1$ then $\|A\|<1$,
perhaps it is because of this one

$\|A\| = \sup_{x\neq 0}(\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|})$
and $\|Ax\| = \|\lambda x\| = |\lambda| \|x\|$
and 
hence $\|A\| = \sup(|\lambda|)$

$\|A\| = \rho(A)<1$
so $\|A\|<1$

**EDIT : -**

I see this but for only $||A||_{2} = \sqrt{\rho(A^{*}A}) $ and $A^{*}$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$ , so in case of say real Symmetric matrix $A$ , $A^{*} = A^{T}$ so $||A||_{2} = \sqrt{\rho(A^{2})} = \sqrt{(\rho(A) )^ 2} < 1 ,$ since $\rho(A)<1$ implying $||A||_{2}<1$,but what about its natural norm that is $\|A\| = \sup_{x\neq 0}(\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|})$?

Comment: In your proof you seem to be using $\|A\| = \rho(A)$, which is [false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Matrices).

Comment: Not only is $\|A\| = \rho(A)$ false in general, but if you start from that assumption then the question is pretty meaningless :).

Comment: Regarding your edit: for a real matrix, $A^* = A^\top$, not $A^* = A$.

Answer (score 2):

The "iff", or your so-called "corollary", are wrong. Counterexample: when $A$ is the $2\times2$ Jordan block for the eigenvalue $1-\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$ we have $\rho(A)=1-\epsilon<1$ but $\|A\|_2\ge\|(1,0)\,A\|_2=\|(1-\epsilon,1)\|_2>1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gelfand's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand.27s_formula): $$\rho(A) = \lim_{k\to \infty} \|A^k\|^{\frac{1}{k}}.$$

Otherwise, follow [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179105/operator-norm-vs-spectral-radius-for-positive-matrices), you have $\rho(A) \leq \|A\| \leq \rho(A)^2$.

Comment: I believe the bound in the linked post is only in the context of integer matrices.  For one thing, the inequality you propose makes no sense for $\rho(A) < 1$.